# Tab OnClickListener in another activity

Tags: android, class, android-tabhost, tabwidget, onclicklistener

**My Tools.java :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.tabtools);

Resources res = getResources();
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

// TabDados
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ToolDadosTubuCirc.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("dados")
        .setIndicator("Dados", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icondados))
        .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
// TabLegenda
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ToolLegendaTubuCirc.class);
spec = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("legenda")
        .setIndicator("Legenda",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.iconlegenda))
        .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
// TabCalcular
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ToolCalcularTubuCirc.class);
spec = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("calcular")
        .setIndicator("Calcular",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.iconcalcular))
        .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
// TabCorrente
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);}}
```

**My tabtools.xml**

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_above="@+layout/rowLog"
android:layout_below="@+layout/rowLine" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The first tab is called the class "ToolDadosTubuCirc.java" and this activity has the following code:**

```
package br.com.mobile4you.engtools;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ToolCalcularTubuCirc extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.toolcalculartubucirc);

    }
}
```

**How to create an event within the file onClickListener "ToolDadosTubuCirc.java"?
I need to create a function that when people click on the tab "calcular" do some test data it should fill in the tab "dados".

**I have 3 tabs: tab1 = data; tab2 = legend; tab3 = calculate. 
The corrent tab is the "data". I need to check when the User click on the tab "calculate" to all fields of the tab "Data" was completed. I do not know create the onclickListener event for TabDados in other activity(class). I dont know the id of the tabhost and TabWidget.
How to create this event? Thank you!****

*If the id of my tabhost is standard android and my id is also TabWidget. I am not able to do this event. Help me.*

Comment: Have you tried to use `onTabChanged(String tabId)`?

Answer (score 0):

Question is unclear

"I need to create a function that when people click on the tab".  Assume mTabWidget is your TabWidget control, and nTabOffset = 0, i.e. the offset of your dados tab:

```
mTabWidget.getChildAt(nTabOffset).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
   // TODO:
 }
});
```

TabHost will instantiate your activity and call onCreate().  You would initialize your activities views there, though if you want a tab click event to re-initiate some data update, you could do this via the onClick() method above, perhaps sending a broadcast intent that is registered in your activity.

Comment: I have 3 tabs:
tab1 = data;
tab2 = legend;
tab3 = calculate.

The corrent tab is the "data".
I need to check when the User click on the tab "calculate" to all fields of the tab "Data" was completed.

I do not know create the onclickListener event for TabDados in other activity(class).
I dont know the id of the tabhost and TabWidget.
How to create this event?